# Outlook addin JS- NPM run build missing JS files

Tags: npm, webpack, build, babeljs

I am working on creating an Outlook addin project following the below tutorial:-
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/quickstarts/outlook-quickstart?tabs=yeomangenerator
During development i added some extra JavaScript files(like helper.js, settings.js) which contains some common and helper functions which are work fine while running locally,
Now when i run "npm run build" command for generating a published version of the project to be deployed on server these files are missing and thus published project is not working due to missing functions.
Below is my project.

[project structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3svqY.png)

[missing helper and setting folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AWcB1.png)

below is my webpack.config.js boiler plate code

```html
module.exports = async (env, options) => {
  const dev = options.mode === "development";
  const buildType = dev ? "dev" : "prod";
  const config = {
    devtool: "source-map",
    entry: {
      polyfill: ["core-js/stable", "regenerator-runtime/runtime"],
      taskpane: "./src/taskpane/taskpane.js",
      commands: "./src/commands/commands.js",
      landing: "./src/landing/landing.js"
    },
    resolve: {
      extensions: [".html", ".js"]
    },
    module: {
      rules: [
        {
          test: /\.js$/,
          exclude: /node_modules/,
          use: {
            loader: "babel-loader", 
            options: {
              presets: ["@babel/preset-env"]
            }
          }
        },
        {
          test: /\.html$/,
          exclude: /node_modules/,
          use: "html-loader"
        },
        {
          test: /\.(png|jpg|jpeg|gif)$/,
          loader: "file-loader",
          options: {
            name: '[path][name].[ext]',          
          }
        }
      ]
    },
    plugins: [
      new CleanWebpackPlugin(),
      new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
        filename: "taskpane.html",
        template: "./src/taskpane/taskpane.html",
        chunks: ["polyfill", "taskpane"]
      }),
      new CopyWebpackPlugin({
        patterns: [
        {
          to: "taskpane.css",
          from: "./src/taskpane/taskpane.css"
        },
        {
          to: "[name]." + buildType + ".[ext]",
          from: "manifest*.xml",
          transform(content) {
            if (dev) {
              return content;
            } else {
              return content.toString().replace(new RegExp(urlDev, "g"), urlProd);
            }
          }
        }
      ]}),
      new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
        filename: "commands.html",
        template: "./src/commands/commands.html",
        chunks: ["polyfill", "commands"]
      }),
      new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
        filename: "landing.html",
        template: "./src/landing/landing.html",
        chunks: ["polyfill", "dialog"]
      })
    ],
    devServer: {
      headers: {
        "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*"
      },      
      https: (options.https !== undefined) ? options.https : await devCerts.getHttpsServerOptions(),
      port: process.env.npm_package_config_dev_server_port || 3000
    }
  };

  return config;
};
```

Could you please help

Comment: The tutorial you are referring to doesn't include webpack or babel. It seems you need to include missing js files to the source map.

Answer (score 0):

Finally found the solution, We need to include the custom/helper js files by

1. marking the functions as export & making them require on the main files that needs &
2. then use the functions exported and
3. once we run "npm run build"  function is available as the part of main file which made it required
   below is the example of the same

   //custom or helper file in a subfodler
   sample.js
   export function sampleFunc() {
   //some code`enter code here`
   }

   taskpane.js // main file where we need to use
   const samJs = require("./../helpers/sample"); // without extesion
   //Call the function
   var data = samJs.sampleFunc